# How To Include Xml File In Other Xml File

Tags: java, testng

Iwant to include or call dependencies xml file in testng xml file any helps????

**I want Include**

**dependencies.xml**:

```
    <groups>
    <group name="publierlivraison" depends-on="creerlivraison"></group>

    </groups>
```

**File in**

**TestNG.xml** :

```
    <test name="Managetestss" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>

                     dependencies.xml????? how to include here this file 
    <classes>
     <class name="com.az.tests.commun.TNR_Client_001_Ajouter_Client" />
    <class name="com.az.tests.client.TNR_Client_002_Rechercher_Client" 

    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <document xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <p>Text of my document</p>
  <xi:include href="copyright.xml"/>
</document>
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XInclude

Answer (score 0):

Below example should work to include external file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng-1.0.dtd" 
[<!ENTITY parent SYSTEM "./src/test/resources/dependencies.xml">]>

<suite name="suite1">
  <test name="Managetestss" preserve-order="true">
    &parent;
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.az.tests.commun.TNR_Client_001_Ajouter_Client" />
      <class name="com.az.tests.client.TNR_Client_002_Rechercher_Client" 
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

However the `dependencies.xml` you provided will not work because testng DTD doesn't support `group` tag under `groups`. Refer [groups-of-groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#groups-of-groups) and [dependencies-in-xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml)